# Passing in parameter values through Java but without setting environment variables

Tags: java, variables, parameters, liquibase, templating

If I have an existing changelog like below, every time a new user is created in my app, I'd like to use Java to dynamically pass in that user name to `${userName}` and then call the Liquibase Java API to actually create the table in my database.

Is there a way to do this without having to set environment variables each time? I imagine it'd be a problem if I have multiple new user creations happening at once, managing the same environment variable would be troublesome. I'm looking for a more programmatic way of passing them in via Java, like passing in Strings or using info from the JDBC connection string.

```xml
<changeSet id="1" author="liquibase">
   <createTable tableName="${userName}">
       <column name="id" type="int">
       <constraints primaryKey="true"/>
       </column>
       
       <column name="somethingelse" type="int">
       <constraints nullable="false"/>
     </column>
   </createTable>
</changeSet>
```

Comment: Sounds really weird to me that you need a new table for each user. Ending up with a dynamic number of identical tables is really what you want ? Or did I miss something ?

Comment: I've found a solution, but basically, every time a user is created, I want to create a new table for them. I've posted the code in my solution. Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Why a new table for each user ? Why not a field `user` in one unique table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it is possible to pass in the changelog parameter via Java. This can be done by:

```
Database database = DatabaseFactory.getInstance().findCorrectDatabaseImplementation(new JdbcConnection(conn));
                Liquibase liquibase = new liquibase.Liquibase(getChangelogFilePath(), new ClassLoaderResourceAccessor(), database);
                // Requires changelog to contain parameter for account_name in the form ${_____}
                liquibase.setChangeLogParameter("<your parameter here>", <some string in the form ${_____}>);
                liquibase.update(new Contexts(), new LabelExpression());
```

The `.setChangeLogParameter()` is how it is done. Note that once this value is set, it cannot be set to another value, unless you create a new Liquibase object.